# Parsing JSON - script fails when an expected element is missing

Tags: json, parsing

I have the following line in my script, building a string based on news feed data retrieved from JSON:

```
 var buildstring = "<table><tr><img src=" + obj.value.items[x]["media:content"].url + "> <b>" + obj.value.items[x].title + "</b><br /><td>" + obj.value.items[x].description.content + "</td></tr></table><br />";
```

In general it works fine - except for one thing.  The feed that is being parsed occasionally doesn't have an image file associated with a particular title and description, and in that case, the entire script fails.

Is there any way to get the script to skip over any missing item in the feed and to build the string from the items that are there?  E.g. if there is no image file for a story, the string consists of just the title and description?  In the typical case I am taking 5 - 10 stories - if all of them have the 3 elements (image, title and description.content), it's all fine.  If one story is missing the image file, I get nothing at all.

Thanks for any advice or assistance.

EDIT:

More complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"> </script><script type="text/javascript">

function pipeCallback(obj) {
document.write("<div id=testdiv><b>LATEST NEWS</b><hr>");
var x;
for (x = 0; x < obj.count ; x++)
{
var imageurl = obj.value.items[x]["media:content"].url ? obj.value.items[x]["media:content"].url : "http://static.jquery.com/org/images/project/jquery-project-sm.png";
var buildstring = "<table><tr><img src=" + imageurl + "> <b>" + obj.value.items[x].title + "</b><br /><td>" + obj.value.items[x].description.content + "</td></tr></table><br />";
document.write(buildstring);
buildstring = null;
}
document.write("</div>");

}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered using some templating code to do this?

Comment: Solved it - thanks to both of you!  This was the key line:   var imageurl = (typeof obj.value.items[x]["media:content"] == 'undefined') ? "http://placeholderimage.png" : obj.value.items[x]["media:content"].url;  I'd like to give a point to both of you, but in fairness, given this is a coding forum, dbaseman gets it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a ternary expression to build the string:

```
var textOnly = "<b>" + obj.value.items[x].title + "</b><br /><td>" + obj.value.items[x].description.content + "</td></tr></table><br />";
var buildstring = (typeof obj.value.items[x]["media:content"] == 'undefined') ? 
    "<table><tr><td><img src=" + obj.value.items[x]["media:content"].url + "></td>" + textOnly 
    : "<table<tr><td></td>" + textOnly;
```

Obviously this gets really ugly, fast, which is why they invented client-side templating ([JQuery templating](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/), [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template), [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), etc, take your pick).

These allow you to separate the data from the markup, so you can write something like this:

```
var template = "<table><tr><td><img src='{{ image }}' /></td><td>{{ title }}</td><td>{{ description }}</td></tr></table>";
```

And you can get the HTML by from the data + template:

```
var html = Mustache.render(template, obj.value.items[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is simply to include placeholder, right? So if there is no image then the placeholder appears...

This would be achieved like this:

```
var imageurl = obj.value.items[x]["media:content"].url ? obj.value.items[x]["media:content"].url : "http://link.to.default/image.png";
var buildstring = "<table><tr><img src=" + imageurl  + "> <b>" + obj.value.items[x].title + "</b><br /><td>" + obj.value.items[x].description.content + "</td></tr></table><br />";
```

Comment: Sam - this looks the ideal solution, but I can't make it work - I've edited the original post to show the markup with your suggestion.  The original data source is a Yahoo pipe (JSON).

Comment: The updated code still fails from the point where it first encounters an item with no image.  Thanks for your suggestion - any clues where I've gone wrong?